# Combine extensions methods for various enum types to a simpler way in C#

Tags: c#, enums

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Anyone know a good workaround for the lack of an enum generic constraint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244/anyone-know-a-good-workaround-for-the-lack-of-an-enum-generic-constraint)
>   [Can I use inheritance with an extension method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13043827/can-i-use-inheritance-with-an-extension-method)

I have created extensions methods for various enums to get their strings in certain format. Is there a simpler way to make the code looks smart so that I can just add the type and extension method should be created for that type.

```
    public static string GetString(this State p1)
    {
        return p1.ToString("F");
    }

    public static string GetString(this Brand p1)
    {
        return p1.ToString("F");
    }

    public static string GetString(this Status p1)
    {
        return p1.ToString("F");
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand. Why do you create an extension method when you could just as well use ToString() ?

Comment: I swear I answered a similar question within the past week, just with .ToString("N2") instead, but I can't find it...

Comment: A wrapper method overload around a single generic method? I don't get it.

Comment: What you want is a generic constraint of type `enum`, but such a thing does not exist.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244/anyone-know-a-good-workaround-for-the-lack-of-an-enum-generic-constraint

Comment: Found it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13043827/can-i-use-inheritance-with-an-extension-method/13043866#13043866

Comment: `code` public static string GetString(this Enum p1)
        {
            return p1.ToString("F");
        }

Comment: Enums are evil.http://www.colourcoding.net/blog/archive/2009/07/25/enums-are-evil-the-state-pattern.aspx